# Why is PHP adding whitespace to PRINT output?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm having a problem with PHP that I cannot find the answer to:
I'm using PHP5.5 and Flash AS3.

I have a `controlfile.php` which I list the db connection info in.
When I connect via the Flash AS3 login screen, and if all is good, I expect the reply from the PHP file to be `returnMsg=1` and indeed that is exactly what I get when I check with Charles 3.8.3. and the FLash Movie advances nicely

However, and this is where it starts getting weird, I have now moved my db connection lines from the `controlfile.php` and placed them in a `connect.php`. In the controlfile I have added the line `require_once("connect.php");`
I ran the same scenario and my Flash movie does not progress beyond the login screen as it should. I checked via Charles proxy and was indeed still getting the `returnMsg=1` from the `controlfile.php`. Confused I checked the flash movie and put a trace on the event.target.data - it returned `%20returnMsg=1`. I looked back at Charles and sure enough, although I didn't notice at first, there was a blank space.

My question is What is causing this space to suddenly manifest itself when I use a require_once. As a beginner to PHP  none of this makes any sense. as a work around I can ask the `controlfile.php` to print `returnMsg=1&returnMsg=1` and the output Charles is `<space>returnMsg=1&returnMsg=1`. If the Flash trace it appears as `%20returnMsg=1&returnMsg=1` and therefore, beacuse its is actually getting the `returnMsg=1` (without the `%20`) the movie will progress. Sorry for the lengthy question but this is driving me completely nuts... Someone, please help with this PHP thing

Comment: most likely space is just outside `?>` at the end of your included file.

Comment: Or at the beginning of a file, just before `<?php`.

Comment: dev nut dweller and Pierre Jean, thanks for responding. I have checked what you both suggest but am sorry to report that there are no spaces.. Guys I stand corrected... at the ?> of the connect.php there was a space.... Many many thanks for answering something that I have taken a week to realise......   but that is crazy isn't it! why does PHP append it to the PRINT string on the page that calls it???